# Does onTouchEvent() has to extends from MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to catch any `onTouchEvent()` on the `mapview`.

After search lots of questions&answers, I found only when I write my own `MapView(MyMapView)`and define `onTouchEvent`, then use this `MyMapView` in main activity.

Is it the only way??

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the simplest way.  When you extend the MapView there are only a few methods that you need to implement and they are really straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use overlays. See this my answer to the question here: [How to capture location from MapActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772584/how-to-capture-location-from-mapactivity/2144007#2144007)

Not sure if *all* touch events will be routed to the overlay's `onTouchEvent` though.