# Android Overlay Entire Map

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

How would you go about creating and ItemizedOverlay which covers the entire map?

I have multiple markers on the map which are ItemizedOverlay classes.

I want to create another ItemizedOverlay which covers the entire map to intercept touch events which are not on my markers but the map itself.  I have read in other SO questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772584/how-to-capture-location-from-mapactivity) that the only way to do this is via an ItemizedOverlay->onTap.  The problem is I don't know how to create of Drawable marker which covers the entire map.

I have experimented with LinearLayout drawables but it only appears to be able to use a drawable image as a marker.

Here is my code

```
    private class BackgroundOverlay<Item extends OverlayItem> extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    /**
     * @param defaultMarker
     */
    public BackgroundOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker,Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return overlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return overlays.size();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        overlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }
    protected boolean onTap(int index){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Touched background",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
        return true;    
    }

}
```

and to create the overlay

```
        Drawable d=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.full_screen);
    BackgroundOverlay<OverlayItem> lay = new BackgroundOverlay<OverlayItem>(d,this);
    overlayItem = new OverlayItem(this.mapView.getMapCenter(), "", "");
    lay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
    mapOverlays.add(lay);
```

and the drawable xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blue">
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to interrupt the touch events on areas without markers?

Comment: I use the background touch to dismiss a popup view which is displayed when the user taps on a marker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out.  To overlay the entire map you add a simple Overlay subclass with no drawable duh. and use the onTap event.

```
    private class BackgroundOverlay extends Overlay{
    public boolean onTap (final GeoPoint p, final MapView mapView){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Touched background",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        hideOtherFires(mapView.getOverlays());          
        return true;
    }
```

and instantiate before the other overlays so it goes underneath

```
//add a background overlay to intercept touches on background
    BackgroundOverlay lay = new BackgroundOverlay();
    mapOverlays.add(lay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just override Overlay's onTap method in one of your existing ItemizedOverlays:

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.google.android.maps.Overlay#onTap(com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint, com.google.android.maps.MapView)
 */
@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
    super.onTap(p, mapView);
    OverlayItem item = getFocus();
    mapView.refreshDrawableState();
    return false;
}
```

Make sure you pass it to the superclass, otherwise your onTap(int index) won't receive the event.

**To put it differently:**

`onTap(int index)` - detects taps on OverlayItems

`onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView)` - detects taps anywhere on the map